# How to implement authentication for RSS in php

Tags: php, rss

I'm trying to create authentication for my rss

```
require_once "RSS.php";

$rss =& new XML_RSS("http://localhost/rss_server/rssdata.php");
```

The above url pulls the feed. I want an authentication to know which user is accessing the RSS url and only the true user should be access the RSS feed.

I have tried http authentication. But it didn't work, When I tried to access the url directly it showed a authentication prompt.

Can any one help me out...

Comment: You could do it by passing a access token/hash (e.g. md5: http://localhost/rss_server/rssdata.php?token=7815696ecbf1c96e6894b779456d330e)

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass a username and password to the php file, check the info, and if it's correct output the RSS

it goes like this:

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['username']) && isset ($_REQUEST['password'])) {
    if ( user_exists($_REQUEST['username'], $_REQUEST['password']) ) {
        echo outputRSS();
    }
}
```

but you will have to think (or give us more info) how to send those details to the php script.